# How to close a WebView in Metro apps

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, webview

I have `WebView` in a page. I want that web view to close (disappear) down when I click a button how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be more specific, what do you mean close? Disappear?
If so just change the Visibility property in the event handler of the button.

Comment: ya disappear I tried that I couldnt get it done properly for some reason